# In filamentphp Cannot assign null to property.....Widgets\SpecificMemberStat::$tableColumnSearches of type array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, filamentphp

I am trying to include widgets in the resource view that are connected with multiple Relation Managers and getting this error while changing between Relation Managers.

[image]

in my widget:

```
class SpecificMemberStat extends BaseWidget
{
    use InteractsWithPageTable;
    public static string $resource = MemberResource::class;

    protected static ?string $pollingInterval = null;
    public ?Model $record = null;


    protected function getStats(): array
    {
        return [
            Stat::make('Time Since Joining', Carbon::now()->diff($this->record->joining_date)->format('%y years %m months'))->color('success'),
            Stat::make('Total Salary Received','৳ ' .$this->record->salaryPayments->sum('payment_amount'))->color('success'),
            Stat::make('Current Salary', '৳ ' . $this->record->current_salary)->description('Last Promoted ' .Carbon::parse($this->record->promotions->sortByDesc('promotion_date')->first()->promotion_date)->diffForHumans())->color('success'),
            Stat::make('Week Win', $this->record->weeklyWinners->count())->color('success'),
        ];
    }
}
```

in my resource view page:

```
protected function getHeaderWidgets(): array
    {

        return [
            SpecificMemberStat::class,
        ];
    }
```

In my MemberResouce I have this relation manager:

```
    public static function getRelations(): array
    {
        return [
            RelationManagers\LeavesRelationManager::class,
            RelationManagers\WeeklyWinnersRelationManager::class,
            RelationManagers\PromotionRelationManager::class,
            RelationManagers\SalaryIncrementsRelationManager::class,
            RelationManagers\SalaryPaymentsRelationManager::class,



        ];
    }
```

expecting to show the widgets in the Relation Managers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added in widgets

```
public array $tableColumnSearches = [];
```